# Storing value inside text file with php

Tags: php, html

I'm doing a tutorial where you have a form with 5 different values inside of it.
Whenever you hit a value/number inside the form, that number will be saved to a textfile.
So let's say someone hit the value 3 and then 4. The result would be:

textfile.txt:

```
3

4
```

So my question is, how do I send these values to the textfile? Is it the same structure of php coding as if I would sent it to a database?

My form looks like:

```
<form>    
  <div id="rating-area" class="shadow"> 
    <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb1" value="1"/>
    <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb2" value="2"/>
    <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb3" value="3"/>
    <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb4" value="4"/>
    <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb5" value="5"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

I've been searching all day for an answer but without success.

Comment: Check for the file functions in PHP. Go with http://in1.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php to learn more

Comment: Yea file_put_contents() ... but before that i hope you are posting youre form with values ... input fields... or maybe send an ajax call...

Answer (score 1):

Form.php

```
<?php
    //save the text to file
    if( isset($_GET['hit_number']) && is_numaric($_GET['hit_number']) )
      file_put_contents( 'textfile.txt', $_GET['hit_number'], FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
<form>    
  <div id="rating-area" class="shadow">   
    <a href="Form.php?hit_number=1"> <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb1" value="1"/> </a>
    <a href="Form.php?hit_number=2"> <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb2" value="2"/> </a>
    <a href="Form.php?hit_number=3"> <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb3" value="3"/> </a>
    <a href="Form.php?hit_number=4"> <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb4" value="4"/> </a>
    <a href="Form.php?hit_number=5"> <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb5" value="5"/> </a>
  </div>
</form>
```

The link around the img will reload the same page with the hit_number GET param set based on the image clicked.

Comment: A good answer! But I get an error message since it's not a numeric but an image we click on. Or, I think that's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this code.

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('textfile.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, "3");
fwrite($fp, "\n\n");
fwrite($fp, "4");
fclose($fp);

?>
```

If you are newbie please check these http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with following;

**save_number.php**

```
$file = fopen("textfile.txt", "r");
$numbers= array();

while (!feof($file)) {
   $numbers[] = fgets($file);
}

fclose($file);


if (!in_array($_GET["number"], $numbers)) {
    array_push($numbers, $_GET["number"]);
}

file_put_contents("textfile.txt", implode("\n", $numbers), FILE_APPEND);
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("img").on("click", function() {
    var number = $(this).attr("value");
    $.ajax({
        url: "save_number.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: "number=" + number,
        success: function(response) {
            // handle
        }
    });
});
```